# Best options to improve very slow 'related items' query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one of images, and one that describes which images have been liked by which users. This second table just has a row per image/user combination. I want to write a query that will return which other images in the database has as many 'likers' in common as possible. So, the tables look like:

```
images
+----+----------+
| id | filename |
+----+----------+

images_users
+----------+---------+
| image_id | user_id |
+----------+---------+
```

My query is:

```
SELECT images.filename FROM 
  images_users INNER JOIN images ON images.id = images_users.image_id 
   WHERE images_users.user_id IN ( .... list of user IDs ....) 
   AND NOT images.id = <current image id>
  GROUP BY images.id ORDER BY COUNT(images.id) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Which is to say, find all the rows with matching 'likers', group by the image id, order by the count of that, and return the top 10. I also exclude the current image id, since of course that is otherwise always the top hit.

When the list of user IDs I want to match with grows, this query can take minutes to run - although I am only running it on a home PC, not a big server.

I kind of get the feeling that I'm stuck here, in the sense that my data is normalised according to the rules, but it's just a tough job for the server. I have indexes on all the columns in the join, and the query.

Can I represent this information in another way, that might improve the query time?

----- Edited for questions below -----

The explain output for the query is below:

```
explain SELECT filename  from images_users inner join images on id = image_id 
where image_users.user_id in
(162,591,596,603,856,1654,1967,2219,3640,3847,3956,9201,10601) 
and not images.image_id = 41578 group by images.id order by count(images.id) desc limit 10;

"1" "SIMPLE"    "images_users"  "range" "u_id_2,u_id,i_id"  "i_id"  "4" \N  "9086346"   "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "images"    "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "images_users.i_id" "1" ""
```

There are about 10,000 users, about 1.5M images, and about 6M rows in the images_users table.

Comment: Off hand, what you are doing seems like a better fit with a Graph database to hold and mine these relationships. That said, you might try a table with user_id mapping to image_id so you can find the images for the specific users more readily. I would suspect there are more images than users.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what the Explain output of that query might show ?

Comment: @Jason, how would I go about building a graph database? And I would have assumed that my images_users table finds the images that a user has liked readily enough?

Comment: I am thinking of something like Neo4j when I say graph database. They are better for these types of relationships. As for the images_users table, if you think of the number of images to number of users, you will have to search a lot of images to find those specific users. If you invert the relationship in a duplicate table, then you should have a smaller number of users to search through in comparison and you will be searching for the user first then finding the images for that user if that makes any sense.

Comment: @Jason, I'll look at the notion of a graph database, but I think that the images_users table expresses the relationship in both directions already, doesn't it? Ultimately it seems like it's just a big job with a relational DB.

Comment: @DaveBranton If your images_users table is not indexed by user_id with an explicitly added index on that column, then you are going to be having table scans which will be quite slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Graph Database is the answer

I'm answering my own question here, because I took @Jason's comment, followed the link to neo4j, installed it, learnt a bit of its excellent query language Cyper, and bam. Problem solved.

I took all my data, the two million images, and ten million relationships, and pushed them into neo4j. First, I created indexes.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Image(filename)
CREATE INDEX ON :User(name)
```

And then ran the following query for every relationship between user and image. This also creates the nodes for the user and the image as it goes along, if they don't already exist.

```
MERGE (i:Image{filename:'...'})
MERGE (u:User{name:'...'})
CREATE (u)-[:LIKES]->(i)
```

This was a bit slow, and I did end up improving the import process somewhat, but the resulting data is the same. The query for the search then becomes

```
MATCH (n:Image{filename:'...'})<-[]-(u:User)-[l]->(i:Image) 
WITH count(l) AS c, i.filename AS f 
ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 10
```

Which is a much more expressive way of writing a query in any case, and runs an order of magnitude faster than the equivalent MySQL query, on which all the appropriate indexes were present.

Other queries, which would also have ended up as very expensive joins, like show me all the images with greater than five likes, are extremely efficient

```
MATCH (n:Image) where size ( (n)<-[]-() ) > 3 return n.filename 
LIMIT 20
```